# Losing session variables after ahref click

Tags: php, session, href

I'm trying to set `access_key` and `access_secret` as variables in my session. On the first line I do have a `session_start();`.
Now the problem is when my url (containing the `access_key` and `access_secret`) changes I lose both of the session variables.
I do know that setting both of the variables work.

I set the variables like this:

```
$_SESSION['access_key'] = $_GET['access_key'];
$_SESSION['access_secret'] = $_GET['access_secret'];
```

**Session variable when the url still contains the access_key and access_secret.**

```
Array
(
    [state] => xxxx
    [access_key] => xxxx
    [access_secret] => xxxx
}
```

**And when the url changes I lose the value's of both variables.**

```
Array
(
    [state] => xxxx
    [access_key] =>
    [access_secret] => 
)
```

**When I click this link; I lose my session variables.**

`<a href="?someId=<?= $var['id'] ?>">Text</a>`

So my question is: how can I keep both variables saved in a session variable after the url changes and for example the `$_GET['access_key']` is not present anymore in the url.

Comment: If you're losing data in other pages, chances are that the session was lost/not started; enable error reporting.

Comment: Right, but the value of the session variable “state” for example, does still work. So I think the creation of the   was correctly started.

Comment: I think you probably just need to check that those variables were set before you make the assignment e.g. `if (isset($_GET['access_key'])) $_SESSION['access_key'] = $_GET['access_key'];`